# Can remoting configuration be re-configured?

Tags: c#, remoting, .net-remoting

I am working on a desktop application which uses .net remoting. During the start up the remoting layer is configured based on the app.config. I have a requirement of re-configuring the remoting layer at run-time so that I can connect to a different remoting server.

In fact, I could just modify the config file and restart the application, but unfortunately I must verify whether the remoting server exists, and this is not feasible with this approach. I hope I have stated the problem clearly, and would appreciate any help you could provide!

Answer (score 2):

All remoting-configurations can be done programmatically without using any config file. Maybe, you should go that way.

Comment: Hi, Can you direct me to a simple example if you have one.

Comment: Or https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/lucene.net/branches/Lucene.Net_2_9_4g/test/core/Support/TestOldPatches.cs
`Test_Search_FieldDoc` for a server setup 
and `LUCENENET_100_ClientSearch` for client

Comment: Or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.channels.channelservices.registerchannel%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks L.B. +1 for the info and help.